# nltk download [Error 11004] getadderinfo failed

Tags: python, nltk

This is the error when I try to restart the download again
some times it work but since the new win7 I could not download any data from nltk

```
 nltk.download()

showing info http://nltk.github.com/nltk_data/
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
 return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 495, in callit
 func(*args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.py", line 1893, in_monitor_message_queue
self._select(msg.package.id)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. The issue in my case was that when the NLTK downloader started it had the server index as - http://nltk.github.com/nltk_data/

This needs to be changed to - http://nltk.org/nltk_data/

You can change this by going into the NLTK Downloader window and the `File->Change Server Index`.

Comment: I tried your solution but I am getting an error `<urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>` . Can you please help regarding this.

Comment: @mockash Kindly check if you are able to access the links directly from your machine. It might be a firewall issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar issue, reaching `raw.githubusercontent.com` using `jio`.

My issue was a DNS issue.

Try again by changing your Network Provider or Change your hotspot connection to some other network.